# Поиск пути, A*, большие объемы данных

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, разработка-игр, графы, дерево

Добрый день.
Опишу сначала кратко ситуацию, а в конце задам вопросы.

Ипользую A* для поиска пути в одной из онлайн RPG. Мир поделен на 26х25 блоков, каждый состоит из 256х256 ячеек, а ячейка из квадратов 8х8. Возможны несколько слоев на каждой ячейке. За пределами городов, пещер и подземелий препятствия встречаются редко, пространства и проходы, в основном, широкие.

В настоящий момент реализую A* для всего **статистического** мира. Другими словами, мы сначала прокладываем маршрут до нужной точки, а далее уже в процессе движения персонажа, используем тот же A*, но для обхода динамических объектов. Более того, A* для динамических объектов уже реализовал, т.к. динамическая ситуация *доступна только вокруг персонажа* - пара сотен квадратов - работает быстро и хорошо.

Проблемы начинаются, когда мир гораздо больше. А именно:

У нас есть значение F = G + H, где G - стоимость перемещения в определенную ячейку мира (включая расстояние от начала пути), H - оценка стоимости перемещения до точки назначения. *Открытый лист* - точки мира для обработки (из него выбирается значение с минимальным F), *закрытый лист* - уже обработанные точки, которые далее не прорабатываем

Для значения **F** в *открытом листе* использую обычный Heap Sort, где вершина - минимальное значение. Соответственно, вместе с F для каждого квадрата мы храним X, Y, Z, G, H, Parent (28 байт).

*Однако* в алгоритме есть два других условия, которые оба начинаются как "...добавляем текущий квадрат в открытый лист и для всех *квадратов вокруг* выполняем:

1. Если квадрат в **закрытом листе**, тогда...
2. Если квадрат в **открытом листе**, тогда...".

Вопросы:

1. Каким образом в открытом листе (куче), уже отсортированном по F, найти нужные "квадраты вокруг"?
2. Как найти в закрытом листе "квадраты вокруг"? Какой тут алгоритм сортировки использовать?

Какие варинты решения я вижу:

1. Чтобы понять, находится ли квадрат из окружения в *открытом листе*, нам достаточно пройтись только по верхушке кучи, предполагая, что квадраты рядом имеют примерно одинаковое значение F. Но как глубоко искать? А что если один из квадратов имеет более высокое значение F? тогда он будет уже внизу кучи и мы можем до него не добраться. Я так понимаю, последнее маловероятно.
2. Чтобы понять, находится ли квадрат X, Y, Z из окружения в *закрытом листе*, нужно закрытый лист отсортировать по X, далее одинаковые X по Y. И, соответственно, искать делением массива пополам.

Добавлено (17.04):

3. Как вариант, чтобы быстро было, для закрытого листа использовать двумерный массив (X, Y) для каждого блока, где отмечать false/true (закрыт/открыт). Это 4 мб / блок, а всего блоков 650 :(( Как я понимаю, мы их даже "выгрузить" не можем, т.к. пройдя 10 блоков и не найдя пути, алгоритм ж обратно пойдет.

Возможны ли лучшие варианты реализации? Я так понимаю, что можно между блоками мира добавить статистические маршруты на границах, чтобы точно знать куда идти далее. Это и память сэкономит и быстрее будет, т.к. поиск проводится только внутри одного блока до статистического перехода.

Считаю приемлемым, что алгоритм будет выполняться в районе *10-20 секунд на 4-х ядерном процессоре*.

Comment: После слов "а именно" вдруг появляется некое F, а также какие-то открытый и закрытый листы. Не хотите пояснить, о чем речь?

Comment: F = G + H, где G - стоимость перемещения в определенную ячейку мира, H - оценка стоимости перемещения до точки назначения. Открытый лист - точки мира для обработки (из него выбирается значение с минимальным F), закрытый лист - уже обработанные точки, которые далее не прорабатываем

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив  в его тело содержимое комментария, чтобы нужная информация была вся вместе

Comment: Мне кажется что вы слишком расплылись в мыслях или нужно вопрос разбить на несколько других поменьше или сделать более обобщенно. Если хотите с конкретикой то и вопрос должен быть конкретней, если спрашиваете по общим принципам то и вопрос обобщенный.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону иерархического A* (HPA*). Он как раз заточен на ваш случай.

Comment: @Kromster Спасибо. Именно то, что требуется.